# Unmarshal nested map with int keys

Tags: json, dictionary, go, unmarshalling

If I have a `map`, I can Marshal it no problem:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "os"
)

type object map[int]interface{}

func main() {
   obj := object{
      1: "one", 2: object{3: "three"},
   }
   buf, err := json.Marshal(obj)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   os.Stdout.Write(buf) // {"1":"one","2":{"3":"three"}}
}
```

However I want to do the reverse. I tried this:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   buf := []byte(`{"1":"one","2":{"3":"three"}}`)
   var obj map[int]interface{}
   json.Unmarshal(buf, &obj)
   // map[int]interface {}{1:"one", 2:map[string]interface {}{"3":"three"}}
   fmt.Printf("%#v\n", obj)
}
```

Only the top level has the correct type. Is it possible to do what I am wanting?

Comment: It seems right, what are you wanting exactly? The Unmarshal rightly converted your data right?

Answer (score 3):

JSON keys are never anything but strings, that's how the spec is defined, and you can see that in the output of you marshal. So when you try the reverse with `interface{}` as the top level map's value type, the type information for the nested objects is lost. You'd need a custom map type that implements `UnmarshalJSON` to be able to do what you want.

For example:

```golang
type IntKeyMap map[int]interface{}

func (m *IntKeyMap) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    raw := map[int]json.RawMessage{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &raw); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for k, v := range raw {
        // check if the value is a nested object
        if len(v) > 0 && v[0] == '{' && v[len(v)-1] == '}' {
            // The following assumes that the nested JSON object's
            // key strings represent integers, if that is not the
            // case this block will fail.
            obj := IntKeyMap{}
            if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), &obj); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            (*m)[k] = obj
        } else {
            var i interface{}
            if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), &i); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            (*m)[k] = i
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/lmyhqD__Uod

Comment: I just noticed, this fails with input like this `{"1":[{"2":"two"},{"3":"three"}]}`

Comment: @Three Just add an `else if` where you check for and array, i.e. `[` and `]`, the same way the above is checking for object. Then, if true, pass a `[]IntKeyMap` to json.Unmarshal, or, if the array can have mixed types (not all int maps), then unmarshal into `[]json.RawMessage`, and after that unmarshal the individual raw messages.

Comment: @Three and to not repeat yourself you can move the logic from within the loop into a recursive function: https://go.dev/play/p/UsRYtWS4Gyq